# The data string cannot appear when access API in php

Tags: php, sql-server, web-services

I have the ambigous issue, when access the data that cannot show anything, its hard to explain maybe with this picture can to describe all of them
i have data in database

[image]

```
//PLU = 1001151100006 its show the data
//PLU = 1002206200009 its not show the data

$plu = cekget('plu');
$sql = "select Long_Description from item_master where plu = '$plu'";

$datas = array();
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if ($result){
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                extract($row);
                 $datas[] = array("Long_Description" => $Long_Description);
        }     
}
$json = array("status" => 1, "respone" => $datas);
echo json_encode($json);
```

the PLU = 1002206200009  data's should be show **'SSA Abigail Bucket Bag Small Black'**
but its cannot appear, and the ambigous points is when the word **Black** is deleted the data is appear

this is how I try to access the data PLU = 1001151100006 and its appear
[image]

and this the same way I try to access data PLU = 1002206200009 its dissapear
[image]

please anyone who help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with parameter in your SQL statement:

```
<?php
$sql = "select Long_Description from item_master where plu = ?";
$plu = cekget('plu');
$params = array($plu);

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if ($result){
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $datas[] = array("Long_Description" => $row['Long_Description']);
        # Just for test:
        print_r($row, true);
    }     
}
$json = array("status" => 1, "respone" => $datas);
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

If you want to remove non-breaking spaces, use the following statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT Long_Description FROM item_master WHERE REPLACE(plu, NCHAR(0x00A0), '') = ?";
```

Comment: Updated answer with parameters in SQL statement.

Comment: thanks @zhorov you almost right, I need to replace the Long_description

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the column with PLU = 1002206200009 has no space.

```
UPDATE {your_table} SET PLU=TRIM(plu);
```

Let me know if you're still stuck on this issue

Regards

Comment: thanks for respone I really need your idea, but I did your suggest and still doesn't work

Comment: Could you try to  var_dump your query `$sql = "select Long_Description from item_master where plu = '$plu';` and then paste it in your sql_client ?

Comment: I think this issue coused of character \u00a0 in the data string, do you know to solve it?